Unable to acquire a session of Selenium Grid on Gitlab Runner
I stuck with an issue and hope someone could help me with this. Many thansk in advance
I have two docker-based gitlab-runners. Both of them works fine except of codeception task. The codeception task works fine on old server (Centos7) fine, but fails on new one (Alma9). The task fails silently on Selenium grid session aquire step . Gitlab-ci waits 60s and brakes the pipeline.
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v5.1.2 https://stand-with-ukraine.pp.ua
  Generating AcceptanceTesterActions...
Sp\Tests\Codeception\acceptance.acceptance Tests (17) ------
Modules: WebDriver, \Sp\Tests\Codeception\_support\Helper\Acceptance, Asserts
------------------------------------------------------------
CitySelectorCest: Test select city signup
Signature: Sp\Tests\Codeception\acceptance\func\CitySelectorCest:testSelectCitySignup
Test: tests/Codeception/acceptance/func/CitySelectorCest.php:testSelectCitySignup
Scenario --
[service:registry.xxx__docker__gitlab-selenium-server-gitlab-selenium-server-registry.xxx-docker-gitlab-selenium-server] 2024-09-02T15:50:27.210032271Z 01:50:27.208 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session request received by the Distributor: 
[service:registry.xxx__docker__gitlab-selenium-server-gitlab-selenium-server-registry.xxx-docker-gitlab-selenium-server] 2024-09-02T15:50:27.210089649Z  [Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-extensions, --allow-running-insecure-co..., --allow-insecure-localhost, --headless, --window-size=1280,1024, --remote-debugging-port=9222]}}]
  Curl error: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--no-sandbox","--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-extensions","--allow-running-insecure-content","--allow-insecure-localhost","--headless","--window-size=1280,1024","--remote-debugging-port=9222"]},"browserName":"chrome"}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--no-sandbox","--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-extensions","--allow-running-insecure-content","--allow-insecure-localhost","--headless","--window-size=1280,1024","--remote-debugging-port=9222"]},"browserName":"chrome"}}
Operation timed out after 60001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
  WebDriver::debugWebDriverLogs method has been called when webDriver is not set
  WebDriver::_saveScreenshot method has been called when webDriver is not set
  WebDriver::_savePageSource method has been called when webDriver is not set
  Screenshot and page source were saved into '/builds/xxx/xxx/tests/Codeception/_output/' dir
 ERROR 

The main difference between runners is underlying OS. We are in the middle of migration from Centos7 to Alma9. Gitlab-runner configs are similar
Old server: 
 OS: Centos7 
 Docker Version: 26.1.4 
 Gitlab-runner: 17.2.1

New server:
 OS: Alma9
 Docker Version: 27.1.2
 Gitlab-runner: 17.3.1

Does anyone face a similar issue? Could you give me some hints on how to debug the problem?
I've checked the chrome webdriver inside the container. The ps command shows the chrome processes are running inside the container. I've tried to get status before run the codeception. Status looks fine
{
  "value": {
    "ready": true,
    "message": "Selenium Grid ready.",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": "b157013c-00c9-4d10-9550-964ec4acbee1",
        "uri": "http:\u002f\u002f172.17.0.10:4444",
        "maxSessions": 5,
        "osInfo": {
          "arch": "amd64",
          "name": "Linux",
          "version": "5.14.0-427.28.1.el9_4.x86_64"
        },
        "heartbeatPeriod": 30000,
        "availability": "UP",
        "version": "4.24.0 (revision 748ffc9bc3)",
        "slots": [
          {
            "id": {
              "hostId": "b157013c-00c9-4d10-9550-964ec4acbee1",
              "id": "2e4114b7-e4d0-4ad1-8a2d-cd7451736f2c"
            },
            "lastStarted": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "session": null,
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "chrome",
              "browserVersion": "128.0",
              "goog:chromeOptions": {
                "binary": "\u002fusr\u002fbin\u002fgoogle-chrome"
              },
              "platformName": "linux",
              "se:containerName": "",
              "se:noVncPort": 7900,
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          },
          {
            "id": {
              "hostId": "b157013c-00c9-4d10-9550-964ec4acbee1",
              "id": "78661812-a8bf-45cf-9173-12f6dac0a1ff"
            },
            "lastStarted": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "session": null,
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "chrome",
              "browserVersion": "128.0",
              "goog:chromeOptions": {
                "binary": "\u002fusr\u002fbin\u002fgoogle-chrome"
              },
              "platformName": "linux",
              "se:containerName": "",
              "se:noVncPort": 7900,
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          },
          {
            "id": {
              "hostId": "b157013c-00c9-4d10-9550-964ec4acbee1",
              "id": "7a59f794-c223-4898-8df1-8382c464988d"
            },
            "lastStarted": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "session": null,
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "chrome",
              "browserVersion": "128.0",
              "goog:chromeOptions": {
                "binary": "\u002fusr\u002fbin\u002fgoogle-chrome"
              },
              "platformName": "linux",
              "se:containerName": "",
              "se:noVncPort": 7900,
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          },
          {
            "id": {
              "hostId": "b157013c-00c9-4d10-9550-964ec4acbee1",
              "id": "20abf47f-dccf-4db2-a04c-2846b2809b56"
            },
            "lastStarted": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "session": null,
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "chrome",
              "browserVersion": "128.0",
              "goog:chromeOptions": {
                "binary": "\u002fusr\u002fbin\u002fgoogle-chrome"
              },
              "platformName": "linux",
              "se:containerName": "",
              "se:noVncPort": 7900,
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          },
          {
            "id": {
              "hostId": "b157013c-00c9-4d10-9550-964ec4acbee1",
              "id": "c9d7bff3-380c-4f90-9403-17be717ee39e"
            },
            "lastStarted": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "session": null,
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "chrome",
              "browserVersion": "128.0",
              "goog:chromeOptions": {
                "binary": "\u002fusr\u002fbin\u002fgoogle-chrome"
              },
              "platformName": "linux",
              "se:containerName": "",
              "se:noVncPort": 7900,
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

